# How to gett API data through Axios POST request?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get data from API backend where I have CORS configured. When request is sent to the server no error is displayed inside browsers inspection tool:

[image]

In my Flask debug I also see that requests worked as expected:

```
192.168.1.33 - - [13/Mar/2023 16:41:01] "OPTIONS /api/token/tokens HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.33 - - [13/Mar/2023 16:41:01] "POST /api/token/tokens HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

But when I try to console.log the response data, its empty.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import axios from 'axios';

const config = {
headers: {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  }
}

let data = {
    "username":"test",
    "email":"test@gmail.com",
    "password": "testpass"
 }

axios.post('http://192.168.1.55:5000/api/token/tokens', data, config).then((response) => {
  console.log(response.data.data); 
}).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
});
</script>
```

However, when I send similar POST requests using Postman tool, it returns data in the body as expected.
Kindly, advice what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Are you sure the requested data has a `.data` key inside? from what I see here you are trying to log `response.data.data`

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(response.data)` before asking? Perhaps you should update the question with that output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you explained, `response.data.data` is empty. As a result, `response.data` exists. So, you will need to check what `response.data` contains, maybe it's just the thing you need instead of `response.data.data`. If you are absolutely sure you should have your content inside `response.data.data` and not `response.data`, then you will need to find out what the server does and what bugs it may have. However, it's probably not the case, it's highly probable that your need `response.data` instead of `response.data.data`, since you received proper content while sending the request in another manner.